# Allow Google Site Search but block Google Bot

Tags: search, gwt, search-engine, google-search, robots.txt

I am looking for some clarity on trying to block Google Bot from specific pages on my site but at the same time allowing them to be indexed in my Google Site Search(GSA).  I cannot find a clear answer on this.  This is my best guess.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /example/custom/

User-Agent: gsa-crawler
Allow: /example/custom/
```

I would like to block Google Bot from indexing any pages with www.example.com/example/custom/ but at the same time index them with GSA.  Would this be the correct implementation in my robots.txt file?  Or would GSA need to go above User-agent: * ?  Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can be helpful:

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html

Security tip: remember hackers search in robots.txt to see what dirs you want to "guard".

Cheers!

Comment: I am not worried about security for these pages, I want users to go to them but I don't want google to index them for duplicate content reasons.  As for the link I looked at it but can not find an answer on it about blocking google bot and allowing GSA.